# Why builtin function abs() don't work with Python lists, but works correctly with NumPy arrays and pandas series (as it would be vectorized)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Why builtin function `abs()` don't work with Python lists, but work correctly with NumPy arrays and pandas series?

Applying built-in `abs()` function to Python list raises an exception

> TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'

Nothing surprising, it's in concordance with documentation:

> abs(x)
>   Return the absolute value of a number. The argument may be an integer or a floating point number.
>   If the argument is a complex number, its magnitude is returned.

But the same function behaves correctly (as a vectorized function) for NumPy arrays and pandas series:

```
In[2]: lst = [2, 0, -1]
In[3]: # abs(lst)             # bad operand type for abs(): 'list'
```

---

```
In[4]: import numpy as np
In[5]: arr = np.array(lst)
In[6]: abs(arr)               # no problem
Out[6]: array([2, 0, 1])
```

---

```
In[7]: import pandas as pd
In[8]: s = pd.Series(lst)
In[9]: abs(s)                 # no problem
Out[9]: 
0    2
1    0
2    1
dtype: int64
```

---

```
In[10]: abs.__class__
Out[10]: builtin_function_or_method
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quoted documentation is obsolete.

The [new documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) (for Python 3.8.3) states:

> abs(x)
>       Return the absolute value of a number. The argument may be an integer or a floating point number. If the argument is a complex number, its magnitude is returned. If x defines __abs__(), abs(x) returns x.__abs__().

The last sentence is new, and it explains the question:

NumPy `ndarray` class and pandas `Series` class both define the magic `__abs__()` method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Python 3.8.3 documentation. Curiously the documentation for 3.6 omits the `__abs__()` alternative (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#abs) although I can indeed use abs with a pandas Series as argument under Python 3.6.8.